# extract dataframe index values into a numpy arrray

Tags: python, pandas

Its been hours and I cannot find the tool to solve this little issue that I having. I want to extract the count of index values of a pandas dataframe into a numpy array.

here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item' : [1,2,3], 'quantity': [10,15,22]})
```

and I have done this:

```
r = np.array(df.index.value_count.tolist())
```

but this seems horribly wrong but I cannot do better and it does not work. and to be honest I don't know what to do do to make it working. I am trying to achieve this:

```
r = [0,1,2]
```

any help on this would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Index values are unique, so I'm not sure what you mean by the count of index values: r = df.index.values.tolist() should work to give you the list of index values

Comment: As katardin said, it doesn't make much sense to count the index values. Your title doesn't mention counts, is that even what you want to do? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below:

```
r = np.array(df.index.values.tolist())
```

This will transform the index values of your df to a list and then an numpy array.

Comment: thanks, this gives me an array. I did r = np.array2string(r, separator= ','), after it and it made the trick. would there be a more pytonic way to do this?

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Unless you alter it the default index for a new dataframe is a very simple sequence of numbers from 0 onward.

Comment: make categorical index values for a bar chart but I found out that an array works fine. thank you.

Comment: Why use this instead of `df.index.to_numpy()` ? Or even just `df.index.values`, if you're on an older version of Pandas.